# This part fell off my car yesterday - what is it?

Tags: honda, part-identification

[image: Mystery Part]

I drive a 2008 Honda Fit, and yesterday I found this on my driveway, resting under my front end. I know little to nothing about cars, but this looks simple enough that I think I could replace it if I only knew what it was.

Judging by the location of the rest of the part (this is the passenger side; the driver's side is still attached), this seems to be some kind of protective piece that keeps debris from ending up in my radiator from below.

So, Internet people who are smarter than me about this sort of thing: what is this dingus?

Comment: Haha! I know what it is and where it goes ... A name?? Not a chance. Hopefully someone can come up with a part name/number for you, lol :-) If it makes you feel better, you can run without this without too much worry.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I was relatively safe for a while, but I think it's probably something I don't want to go without forever. I drive almost 400 miles a week just commuting to & from work, so that's a lot of time to leave it exposed.

Comment: For what its worth, this probably came off from too many front end parking jobs where the undercarraige of your car scraped on the curb (thus the tear/rip marks). We've all done it, and it looks like you've done it one too many times.

Comment: @n00b I've only had the car for a year, so probably several people have done too many. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That looks like the front edge of a [splash shield](http://www.carparts.com/results/?N=0&Nr=AND%28universal:0%29&Ntk=Main&Ntx=mode%20matchallany&Nty=1&PN=0%209244&VN=4294967113%204294962818%204294962686%204294967132%204294966554&universal=0) (for certain values of "front").  You're right that it is protecting things coming up from below: splashes, sand and general road gunk.  It's also likely part of the aerodynamics of the vehicle (admittedly a very small part).

The link above is to an example vendor (who's selling the linked part for approximately $30 US).  However, here's a [more complete breakdown of the parts](http://www.fitfreak.net/forums/1st-generation-gd-01-08/62945-front-splash-shield-help.html) in that area:

[image]

As you can see, there are a lot of little trim bits.  None of them are super critical but I'm sure it's annoying to drive around without them (so tacky!).

Comment: Yep, it's the thing marked #6 in the picture. There's actually a person in that post that has the exact part number too. Thanks!